Getting embedding error while using AzureOpenAiEmbeddings with GPT-35-turbo
I am getting below error

The embeddings operation does not work with the specified model, gpt-35-turbo. Please choose different model and try again

I am using the code provided at this Code_link
I tried with "text-embedding-ada-002".
Below is the code
import os
import tempfile
import config as cg
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAI, AzureOpenAIEmbeddings

import mlflow

# Set this to `azure`
os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"] = "azure"
os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY'] = cg.openai_key
os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT'] = cg.Azure_endpoint
os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME'] = cg.deployment
os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION'] = cg.openai_api_version

assert (
    "AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT" in os.environ
), "Please set the AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT environment variable. It is the base URL for your Azure OpenAI resource. You can find this in the Azure portal under your Azure OpenAI resource."

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
    persist_dir = os.path.join(temp_dir, "faiss_index")

    # Create the vector db, persist the db to a local fs folder
    loader = TextLoader("state_of_the_union.txt")
    documents = loader.load()
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
    docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
        azure_deployment=cg.deployment,
        model="text-embedding-ada-002"
    )
    db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
    db.save_local(persist_dir)

    llm = AzureOpenAI(
        deployment_name=cg.deployment,
        model_name=cg.MODEL_NAME,
    )
    # Create the RetrievalQA chain
    retrievalQA = RetrievalQA.from_llm(llm=llm, retriever=db.as_retriever())

    # Log the retrievalQA chain
    def load_retriever(persist_directory):
        embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
            model="text-embedding-ada-002"
        )
        vectorstore = FAISS.load_local(persist_directory, embeddings)
        return vectorstore.as_retriever()

    with mlflow.start_run() as run:
        logged_model = mlflow.langchain.log_model(
            retrievalQA,
            artifact_path="retrieval_qa",
            loader_fn=load_retriever,
            persist_dir=persist_dir,
        )

# Load the retrievalQA chain
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model.model_uri)
print(loaded_model.predict([{"query": "What did the president say about Ketanji Brown Jackson"}]))

I have tried this way as well
    embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
        azure_deployment=cg.deployment
    )
    db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
    db.save_local(persist_dir)

    llm = AzureOpenAI(
        deployment_name=cg.deployment,
        model_name=cg.MODEL_NAME,
    )


I have mentioned all the details already

I have run the same code which is given in the link, but it didn't work.
